# bash script - nohup not displaying output on my terminal

Tags: linux, bash

I setup my start_java.sh script as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "starting process"
nohup java XXX
```

When I run:

> [root@box ~]# bash start_java.sh

it prints

> starting process

However if I run

```
nohup java XXX
```

It prints:

> [1] 19852

Why do I not see this when I run the bash script?
I want to see

> starting process
>
> [1] 19852

Comment: If you are trying to build a startup script for some kind of daemon, you might be better off using one of the tools built for this purpose.

Comment: @Zoredache what tools would you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because nohup automagically redirects output to nohup.out.

Comment: So when I run it from the command line why does it output "[1] 19852"...but not when I run it from the script?

Comment: the shell is producing that output to let you know of the backgrounded processes id.

Comment: yes my whole point is why do I not see that when I run start_java.sh?

Comment: the output [1]... is sent to stderr which has not been captured to a file thus you lose it.

Comment: How do I get my script to print stderr so that I can see any errors?

Comment: nohup only redirects stdout and stderr if they're connected to a terminal.  To keep it from redirecting, you can launder stderr through `cat` like this: `nohup java XXX 2> >(cat >&2)`  Note that this depends on command substitution, which is a bash-only feature; if you're using some other shell, it's still possible it just takes more work.